# How can I convert from a{a{} b{}} to a[a[],b[]] using php preg_match?

Tags: php, arrays, json, preg-match

```
Group test
{
    Group test1
    {
        #-# Type    Val
        1   typ1    10
        2   typ2    10
        3   typ3    10
    }
    
    Group test2
    {
        #-# Type    Val
        1   typ1    10
        2   typ2    10
    }
}
```

How can I convert the above structure to the following result.

```
$result=[
    "test"=>[
        "test1"=>[
            0=>["#-#","Type","Val"],
            1=>["1","typ1","10"],
            2=>["1","typ1","10"],
            3=>["1","typ1","10"]
        ],
        "test2"=>[
            0=>["#-#","Type","Val"],
            1=>["1","typ1","10"],
            2=>["1","typ1","10"]
        ]
    ]
];
```

I tried many patterns, but failed.

I tried with regex pattern and explode function. I Failed in Recursive function.
I want to get the output as array or json. How can i do it.Thanks....

Comment: You don't. Nested structures cannot be parsed by regular expressions as they are, by definition, not regular. What you need is a _parser_ and the easiest way to get one of those is to look at the code that generated your input. Alternatively, it would be much simpler if the thing that generates the data did so in common format for which a parser is already available, eg: actual JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach in two steps: the first checks the whole string syntax with a recursive pattern, if this one is correct, then the second step parse the string with a recursive function.

```
$str = <<<'STR'
Group test
{
    Group test1
    {
        #-# Type    Val
        1   typ1    10
        2   typ2    10
        3   typ3    10
    }
    
    Group test2
    {
        #-# Type    Val
        1   typ1    10
        2   typ2    10
    }
}
STR;

$pattern = <<<'REGEX'
~
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<group>
        Group \s+ \g<groupName> \s* { \s*
            (?:
                \g<group> (?: \s+ \g<group>)*
              |
                \g<line> (?: \h*+ \s+ \g<line> )*
            )?
            \s*
        } 
    )
    
    (?<groupName> \w+ )
    (?<line> \g<value> (?: \h+ \g<value>)* )
    (?<value> [^\s{}]+ )
)

\A \s* \g<group> \s* \z (*:MAIN_GROUP) 
~x
REGEX;

function group2array($group) {
    $ret = [];
    $index = 0;
    
    // this pattern extracts the group name and the group content
    preg_match(
        '~Group \s+ (?<name> \w+ ) \s* { \s* (?<content> .* \S ) \s* } ~sx',
        $group, $match
    );
    $name = $match['name'];
    $content = $match['content'];
    
    $ret[$name] = [];
    
    preg_match_all( // this one extracts groups or lines of values
        '~
           \s* (?<group> Group \s+ \w+ \s* { [^{}]*+ (?: \g<group> [^{}]* )*+ } )
          | 
           \s* (?<line> [^\s{}]+ (?: \h+ [^\s{}]+ )* )
        ~x',
        $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER
    );
    
    foreach($matches as $m) {
        if (isset($m['line'])) {
            $ret[$name][$index++] = preg_split('~\s+~', $m['line']);
        } else {
            $group = group2array($m['group']);
            $ret[$name][key($group)] = current($group);
        }
    }
        
    return $ret;
}
    
if ( preg_match($pattern, $str) ) { // check the string syntax before parsing
    $result = group2array($str);
    echo json_encode($result), PHP_EOL,
         print_r($result, true), PHP_EOL;
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/1QhM1)

Comment: It works when there is 1, but how do I do it when there are 10 groups.
Group1{...}Group..n{...} https://3v4l.org/SYo3X

Comment: All data https://3v4l.org/iZ7FW

Answer (score 0):

I did a study in this way, but it was not enough. some array data is empty

```
<pre>
<?php 
$data=[];
$number=[];
$temp=null;
$op=stream_context_create(array("ssl"=>array("verify_peer"=>false,"verify_peer_name"=>false)));
$f1=file_get_contents('https://huc.re/data.txt',false,$op);
$f2=preg_split('/\r|\n/si', $f1);
foreach($f2 as $k=>$f3){
    $ilk_karakter = substr($f3 , 0 , 1);
    if($ilk_karakter != "#"){
        if(strstr($f3,"{")){
            if($f3=="{"){
                $last=$k-1;
                $g=trim(str_replace("Group","",$f2[$last]));
                $data[$g]=null;
            }
        }elseif(strstr($f3,"}")){
            if($f3=="}"){
                unset($last);
            }
        }else{
            if(isset($last)){
                $data[$g].=$f3.PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }
}
//STEP 2
foreach($data as $k1=>$d1){
    $ff2=preg_split('/\r|\n/si', $d1);
    if(strstr($d1,"Group")){
        $data[$k1]=[];
        foreach($ff2 as $k=>$f3){
            if(strstr($f3," Group") and !strstr($f3,"       Group")){
                $last=$k;
                if(isset($ff2[$last])){
                    $g=str_replace("%","",rawurlencode(utf8_decode(trim(str_replace("Group","",$ff2[$last])))));
                    if(trim($f3) != ""){
                        $data[$k1][$g]=null;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if(trim($f3) != ""){
                    $data[$k1][$g].=$f3.PHP_EOL;
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        $data[$k1]=[];
        for($x=0;$x<count($ff2);$x++){
            $a=explode("    ",$ff2[$x]);
            if(count($a)>3){
                if(trim($ff2[$x]) != ""){
                    $b=array_values(array_filter($a));
                    $data[$k1][$x]=$b;
                }
            }
        }
        $data[$k1]=array_values($data[$k1]);
    }
}
//STEP 3
foreach($data as $k1=>$d1){
    foreach($d1 as $k2=>$d2){
        if(!is_array($d2)){
            $ff2=preg_split('/\r|\n/si', $d2);
            if(strstr($d2,"Group")){
                $data[$k1][$k2]=[];
                foreach($ff2 as $k=>$f3){
                    if(strstr($f3,"     Group") and !strstr($f3,"   Group")){
                        $last=$k;
                        if(isset($ff2[$last])){
                            $g=str_replace("%","",rawurlencode(utf8_decode(trim(str_replace("Group","",$ff2[$last])))));
                            if(trim($f3) != ""){
                                $data[$k1][$k2][$g]=null;
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(trim($f3) != ""){
                            if(isset($data[$k1][$k2][$g])){
                                $data[$k1][$k2][$g].=$f3.PHP_EOL;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $data[$k1][$k2]=[];
                for($x=0;$x<count($ff2);$x++){
                    $a=explode("    ",$ff2[$x]);
                    if(count($a)>3){
                        if(trim($ff2[$x]) != ""){
                            $b=array_values(array_filter($a));
                            $data[$k1][$k2][$x]=$b;
                        }
                    }
                }
                $data[$k1][$k2]=array_values($data[$k1][$k2]);
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($data);

?>
```